# How to pass maven "--also-make" option via pom.xml to command line

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Let`s say there is a parent project A that has modules B and C in its pom.xml.

```
Project A
    |-pom.xml
    |----------->ModuleB
    |               |->pom.xml
    |----------->ModuleC
    |               |->pom.xml

<modules>
    <module>B</module>
    <module>C</module>
</modules>
```

The module C itself has some dependency that belongs only to this submodule. This dependency should be built before module C, so I want to call "-am" (--also-make) option when "mvn install" is called for C.

Maven is being executed remotely, all I have is pom files. Build job runs on remote Jenkins, it uses the current profile in project A parent pom, only this profile must be used.

I though it can be done in module C`s pom, in configuration of maven-compiler-plugin, for example?

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>${jdk.source}</source>
            <target>${jdk.target}</target>
            **<arguments>-am</arguments>** <!--smth like this maybe?-->
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

I also thought about creating another pom.xml to have only submodule C and its dependency in the right order, and to be used instead of current submodule C in parent pom, but want to try -am option first. Besides, I do not quite see now where to put this new pom, because we are already at parent A level.

Probably the whole project structure should be refactored, but it is what I have for now.

Upd: below is less simplified current project structure.

```
Project A (maven parent for B, C, D)
    |-pom.xml
    |----------->ModuleB
    |               |->pom.xml
    |----------->folder
        |----------->folder
            |----------->ModuleC
            |               |->pom.xml
    |----------->ModuleD
    |               |->pom.xml

<modules>
    <module>B</module>
    <!-- <module>D</module> | initially was here, now needs to be only C's dependency -->
    <module>C</module>
</modules>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--also-make option can be used when projects specified are also listed in the modules section of the aggregator(reactor) pom.xml. Since you don't have the required projects in your modules section You can't use it in your current setup.

You can just add the extra projects to your current modules section and this will fix your problem. (You don't have worry about order of modules you write, Maven will build them in the correct order for you. And you don't have to use also-make)

You can also use the solution you suggested in the question. It does not have to be parent of C, It can be just the aggregator of C and its dependencies.( I don't think this is neccessary. You can just add all of them to your current modules section)

Also [parent pom](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance) and [aggregator pom](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation) are different concepts.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm sorry for oversimplifying the project structure. Please see the update below the question. If you were talking about adding the dependency to the parent project A pom, this is how it worked. But the current challenge (and it's not up to me) is to make D only module C`s dependency and to exclude it from project A modules (although it will, of course, still influence the whole project building). As far as I understand, module is something only below the current module. Thinking about moving dependency D to a folder below and making a common aggregator for D & C

Comment: Anyway, wanted to know what other alternatives are there before physically moving module D in order to make a common aggregator

Comment: @nonrandom_passer You dont have to move it to another folder. You can just give relative paths in the modules section. (ex <module>../../B</module>)

Comment: @nonrandom_passer Also this is applicable to parent pom location. Parent pom does not have to be one folder above to current pom. You can use it like <relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath> .  Check this example https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Example_2

Comment: @Silver_Shroud Yes, I have also tried relative paths, should have made a mistake because now it is working, thanks. But anyway I have to create an additional aggregator pom, cannot just mention dependency D as module in C's pom, right? The module C`s pom is "jar" packaging, and maven wants it to be "pom" to use with modules as far as I understood. So I created another pom with "pom" packaging, put there modules D and C each with "jar" packaging. Is it optimal or it can be done without this "pom-in-the-middle"? Thanks.

Comment: @nonrandom_passer This is a valid solution. But at the end, this is not different than adding D directly to the A as a module. (If you can't do it that way, this is fine to.)